Query dynamoDB with datetime filter expression - Incorrect operand
I am try to query my Dynamodb to get items older than 5 min.
My item is stored as:
{
  "main_event_code": {
    "S": "1160"
  },
  "event_code": {
    "S": "9999"
  },
  "last_upload": {
    "S": "2024-05-10T04:09:29.614535Z"
  }
}

Python script:
    current_utc_time = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
    past_time = current_utc_time - timedelta(minutes=5)
    
    # Format both times as ISO 8601 strings
    current_utc_time_iso = current_utc_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
    past_time_iso = past_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')

    # Print the current UTC time and the time minus 5 minutes
    print(f"Current UTC Time: {current_utc_time_iso}")
    print(f"Time 5 Minutes Ago: {past_time_iso}")

    try:
        # Scan the table with a filter for items older than 'past_time'
        response = table.scan(
            FilterExpression="last_upload < :past_time",
            ExpressionAttributeValues={":past_time": {"S": past_time_iso}}
        )

I get:

Error querying DynamoDB table: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Scan operation: Invalid FilterExpression: Incorrect operand type for operator or function; operator or function: <, operand type: M

I know the filterexpression works because, using the AWS CLI, I get the item returned.
aws dynamodb scan --table-name ingestion_queue --filter-expression "last_upload < :val" --expression-attribute-values '{":val":{"S":"2024-05-10T04:23:08Z"}}'


Your issue is because you are using low level syntax {'xx': {'S':.... on a high level client (assumed as your client is named table).
You have 2 choices:

Use the low level client with the current request instead of the resource client.
Use high level syntax: Attr('last_upload').lt(past_time_iso)

More information in this blog post
